# high availability of file in Linux

Tags: linux, files, high-availability

I have a very specific scenario. I have set of config files and I want to maintain it at two different paths which would be nothing but a copy of the same files. For some reason, if one of the location becomes unavailable my process should still access the files from the second location.

How can I achieve this scenario through something like a symbolic link that takes care of this file pointer based on the availability.

Any thoughts or ideas are highly appreciated.

Thanks much -

Comment: I'm not aware of any way this could be done without coding explicitly `fd = open(LOCATION1); if (fd == -1) fd = open (LOCATION2)`. What is your incident scenario? I suppose there's no standard way to handle this because it doesn't happen in reality.

Comment: The probability that a file in an otherwise working file system becomes spontaneously unavailable while everything else continuous working fine is astronomically small, so most likely not worth the effort of coding, testing and maintaining a solution.

Comment: I just wanted to pursue this option only if there's any easy way of doing this. as you said, it may not worth the time spent in coding way out of this. This is very peculiar situation that the application require this kinda setup.